# What is Rage Shake api used in Facebook and Google + like application,Can i use same api in my application?

Tags: android

I recently found this article about Rage Shake which is secret bug reporting tool that facebook used to logs it's bug and get report of it.

So my question is Can i used that Rage Shake API in my android application.
I can not find any APi available like that.If you have some then share with me.

What exact Rage Shake Api do in Facebook ?
I read from this Site [Facebook Droid fooding](http://techcrunch.com/2012/11/24/facebook-droidfooding/)  that Rage Shake used to log application state when device shake .

Comment: This question is not really relevant to developing third-party applications with Facebook.

Comment: i can't get why i got down.What is wrong to get known about Rage Shake used in Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a publicly available feature. One could of course create something similar by using accelerometer APIs and a bug tool backend that provides a reporting API.

Comment: Yes ,i will do that once i really don't find any api that much similar to Rage Shake.

Comment: Do you known what exact rage shake api do in facebook .I just known that if user shake phone then it will get all logs and send it to developer .is there any thing more in Rage shake bug reporting tool.